# binary representation of "jal printf"

Tags: mips

I'm very confused with this.

How do you actually get the binary representation of "jal printf",
assuming that printf is at location 0x4000 and this instruction is at location 0x200.

Anyone can explain this in details?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JAL` is a [J-type instruction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats) with Opcode 3 (`%000011`). `JAL` does not use PC-relative addressing, so the absolute address is stored in the lower 26 bits of the instruction words - except that it's shifted two bits to the right (since instructions need to be word-aligned there's no point in being able to encode jumps to odd addresses). This allows you to jump to any *word* within the first 2^28 bytes of memory (256 MB).

So your `JAL` to address 0x4000 would be encoded as:

`%00001100000000000001000000000000`

which is the same as

`0x0C001000`